# Mouse leave event not working with position absolute and margin-top

Tags: jquery

I have a parent Div containing child div, but mouseleave event of parent div not working with margin >20px  , when margin is >20px  mouseleave get fired on leaveing child div.
how can i manage with margin ~200px , below is my code.

```
<head runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
            .detail
            {
                display: none;
                height:200px;
                padding: 20px;
                border: solid 1px #888;
                width: 400px;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 100;
                left: 20px;
                margin-top:100px;
                background-color: #888;
                opacity: .8;
            }
            .Container
            {
                width: 200px;
            }
            .menu
            {
                width: 50px;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
             <div class="Container">
                            <div class="menu">
                                List1</div>
                            <div class="detail">

                            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>

        </form>
    </body>
    <html>
```

and script is ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.menu').mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).css('background-color','#DFDFDF');
   $(this).parent('div').find('.detail').show();
 })

  $('.Container').mouseleave(function(){

   $(this).find('.menu').css('background-color','');
   $(this).find('.detail').hide();
 })

})

</script>
```

Comment: Please try to build a reproducing, minimized demonstration of the issue on http://www.jsfiddle.net.

Comment: here's a fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/k2Gnq/ but I don't understand where's the problem.. can you reproduce it and update the fiddle?

Comment: i want like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tCPFb/2/)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/k2Gnq  , 'detail div' get hide , when any one want to move from 'menu div' to 'detail div'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/tCPFb/3/

Use `position:relative` instead of `position:absolute` for `.detail` class

Comment: thanks a lot sir , it is working. but can you please explain why it is working with position relative not with absolute.

Comment: `position:relative` property allows the .container div to get the height depending upon the inner content which is not the case with `position:absolute`.